# How we can deploy streamlit app code in snowflake as snowflake object

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, streamlit

I am trying to pull one table data from Snowflake and want to expose it through data editor feature of Streamlit in UI. It is working in my local environment.
I have below files in my repo:

```
main.py
params.py
pages/app.py
```

`main.py` --> This file just contains info about my project

`params.py` --> Parameters required to connect to snowflake

`app.py` --> This file is in pages folder.

This file contains code to connect to snowflake and pull the data from snowflake table and show it in the UI where we can perform update/insert operation and push the changes to snowflake

I want to know how we need to deploy this app in Snowflake. In which way I need to push files to internal stage of snowflake. Also how to parameterize snowflake credentials in `params.py`.

Comment: Hi - as this covered extensively in the documentation, please can you explain what specific issue you are facing? At the moment your question reads a bit like a request for a tutorial on the topic, which is obviously too broad for this forum

Comment: I have gone through the dcumentation and got info. Thanks. I figured out when creating streamlit app in snowflake we doesn't require to create connection separately. It itself offers connection and we can get it by using session = get_active_session(). Now i have a question, I am using data_editor feature which is available from streamlit 1.23.0 version onwards but when I deploy the app I can see version as 1.22.0 by default. How I can overwrite it with latest version of streamlit library.

Comment: I am getting this error when I try to access streamlit app in snowflake. AttributeError: module 'streamlit' has no attribute 'data_editor'

Comment: As of now you cannot change the Streamlit version when running Streamlit in Snowflake. Also be aware that certain open source Streamlit features are not available on Streamlit in Snowflake as described [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/streamlit/limitations#unsupported-streamlit-features)

Comment: Just as a general point for the future, please don't add extra information in comments - always update your question so that the latest information is all available in one place. Also, it's generally considered bad practice on this forum to start a new question within an existing question. In your comment you are really asking a completely new question so ideally you should have closed this question and created a new one